# Android Java TCP / IP socket connection life cycle

Tags: java, android, tcp, connection, nio

I need some implementation TCP/IP on android (obviously by Java)
I came across http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html

However, I am wondering if it is right approach or not.
If you take a look at the code, you can notice that the client http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/src/NioClient.java always creates new connection every time it sends request to the server.

```
public void send(byte[] data, RspHandler handler) throws IOException {
    // Start a new connection
    SocketChannel socket = this.initiateConnection();

    // Register the response handler
    this.rspHandlers.put(socket, handler);

    // And queue the data we want written
    synchronized (this.pendingData) {
        List queue = (List) this.pendingData.get(socket);
        if (queue == null) {
            queue = new ArrayList();
            this.pendingData.put(socket, queue);
        }
        queue.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
    }

    // Finally, wake up our selecting thread so it can make the required changes
    this.selector.wakeup();
}
```

But I don't think it should. Anybody can advise me how to improve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need an implementation of TCP on android? Are you trying to write your own TCP class? What's wrong with the built-ins?

Comment: SocketChannel socket = this.initiateConnection(); every time call this method to send data, it always create new connection. Should I do that, or is there some way to reuse that connection later on.

Comment: It depends on how you are supposed to use the connection. If you just need to "send and forget", this is okay. If you need send data over a period of time, or to receive data as well, then you need to keep the connection.